# How to tell if ParameterInfo type is a collection?

Tags: c#, icollection, gettype, parameterinfo

Is there a way to check whether `ParameterInfo` is a Collection?

I have tried this:

```
ConstructorInfo[] constructorInfos = typeof(T).GetConstructors();
ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = constructorInfos[0];
ParameterInfo[] paramsVar = constructorInfo.GetParameters();
IEnumerable<ParameterInfo> collectionParams = paramsVar.Where(
    x => x.ParameterType.GetElementType() is ICollection);
```

but it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ConstructorInfo[] constructorInfos = typeof(T).GetConstructors();
ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = constructorInfos[0];
ParameterInfo[] paramsVar = constructorInfo.GetParameters();
IEnumerable<ParameterInfo> collectionParams = paramsVar.Where(
    x => typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(x.ParameterType));
```

(note that I've removed the `GetElementType` call and switched `typeof(ICollection)` and `x.ParameterType`)

Comment: @BartoszKP there ya go... I can never remember the order `a.IsAssignableFrom(b)` vs `b.IsAssignableFrom(a)`

Answer (score 2):

Check out the method [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

<s>ConstructorInfo[] constructorInfos = typeof(T).GetConstructors();
    ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = constructorInfos[0];
    ParameterInfo[] paramsVar = constructorInfo.GetParameters();
    IEnumerable collectionParams = paramsVar.Where(
        x => x.ParameterType.GetElementType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ICollection)));</s>

It's easy to confuse `a.IsAssignableFrom(b)` vs `b.IsAssignableFrom(a)`!

@BartoszKP has the [right answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18278391/679692)